# How to run a background task in FastAPI only within working hours without async

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, fastapi, scheduler

Is there any way to run background task in FastAPI which will run from 9am to 9pm every time once the task is completed when the app is idle or not serving requests.

my app handles a bulk of request for a short amount of time ..rest of the time it sits idle.
Is there a way to run scheduled task or using `@repeat_every` to run some background task when the app is idle only within certain time of day.

Any help is really apreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, is there reason to not use async?

Comment: just for simplicity . and I would be fetching data from database in the background task

Comment: erm... I would recommend using async still, but if you must: Then make global 'counter' - increase on start of request handling, decrease on handling completion - that way you can check if any request is currently ongoing or not via simple `counter == 0`. With that and additional check for counter & time combined with `@repeat_every`  should do I guess,

Comment: thanks for the tip . also iam new at async if you have any links related to this implementation in fastapi please share :)

Comment: As usual the best I can think of is [official docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/) about using `async` with fastapi - which also includes very helpful comics illustrating how async operation works!